# Optimize a primary key that I won't use

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I'm creating a new Django (1.7) model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    field1 = models.ForeignKey('OtherModel')
    field2 = models.ForeignKey('AnotherModel', null=True)
    field3 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(db_index=True, null=True)

    other_field1 = models.FloatField(default=0, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('field1', 'field2', 'field3'), )
```

Ideally, I would have liked it to have the tuple (`field1`, `field2`, `field3`) as primary key, but [that's not possible at the moment](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys).
So instead, I have this automatically generated and incremented `id` column that is **required by Django but totally useless for the rest of my code**.

The thing is that I'd like to be able to delete and recreate instances of this model *very often* (almost continuously).
For performance reasons, I'd like to avoid having to use a `create_or_update` approach, as deleting and creating is much quicker from what I've tested (18op/s with the `create_or_update` method, 72op/s with the "delete all and create" method, and I expect these numbers to be higher on our production server).
But I'm afraid to **reach the auto_increment upper limit too** soon (about a year it seems).

Other possibilities that I've imagined :

- using a Bigint primary key: that would work, but it would probably be less effective, especially considering that I will never use this primary key (and [`BigAutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.10/ref/models/fields/#bigautofield) is not available until Django 1.10)
- using an UUID primary key: same stuff (and [`UUIDField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) is not available until Django 1.8)
- using a custom `CharField` primary key that would be something like `"{self.field1.pk}/{self.field2.pk}/{self.field3}"`, but I don't even know if Django can handle a primary key generator based on the instance itself (the advantage though is that it would ensure the unicity even with `null` values on `field2` and `field3`)

What would you suggest (aside from upgrading to a newer version of Django, I know I'm late...)? Do you think I'm looking for too much optimizations?

Stack:

- Django 1.7 (can't upgrade for now)
- PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: Of the alternatives you quote, using `bigint` is definitely the best (fast, uses only 8 bytes of storage). It is tough to be fettered by an ORM.

Answer (score 1):

If you are feeling adventurous, you can try turning the `id` column into a nullable integer column without default.

**Note:** This will break parts of the Model API, the admin and most likely cause all kinds of unforeseen trouble, but depending on your use case it might just do what you want. I'm not saying this is a good idea, I'm just showing you the option.

That being said, here is the necessary migration:

```
migrations.RunSQL([
    "ALTER TABLE myapp_mymodel DROP CONSTRAINT myapp_mymodel_pkey",
    "ALTER TABLE myapp_mymodel ALTER COLUMN id drop default",
    "ALTER TABLE myapp_mymodel ALTER COLUMN id drop not null"]
),
```

You can still create new objects and get existing objects, but you cannot directly save or delete objects:

```
>>> m = MyModel.objects.create(field1=1, field2=2, field3=3)
>>> m
<MyModel: MyModel object (None)>
>>> m.delete()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 886, in delete
    (self._meta.object_name, self._meta.pk.attname)
AssertionError: MyModel object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None.
```

However, you can use `.filter(...).delete()` and `.filter(...).update(...)`:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(field1=1, field2=2, field3=3).update(field3=4)
1
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(field1=1, field2=2, field3=4).delete()
(1, {'myapp.MyModel': 1})
```

---

The `MyModel` I used to test this behavior has three PositiveSmallIntegerFields, not ForeignKeys, but that shouldn't make a difference:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    field1 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    field2 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    field3 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(db_index=True, null=True)

    other_field1 = models.FloatField(default=0, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('field1', 'field2', 'field3'), )
```